# Institutional level earnings data (e.g. MN_EARN_WNE_P10, etc.,) has been updated since FY15. Is there anything more current? When will it be updated?

Tags: education

According to the most recent Scorecard Dictionary, institutional level earnings data (e.g. MN_EARN_WNE_P10, MS_EARN_WNE_P6, etc.,) hasn't been updated since FY15. Is that correct - or is there more current earnings data by institution that I missed? In variation, When will this information be updated, if at all? Lastly, are you aware of any similar alternative sources - at the institutional level.